# Sails.js websocket disconnecting

Tags: javascript, websocket, sails.js

I'm trying to broadcast a message to all users of a room when a socket disconnects

```
afterDisconnect: function(session, socket, cb) {
     var rooms = sails.sockets.socketRooms(socket);
         for(var i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
             if(rooms[i].indexOf("gameRoom") > - 1) {
                 sails.sockets.broadcast(rooms[i], 'byeUser', socket.id, socket);
           break;
             }
         }
     return cb();
  }
```

Thing is when the event occurs the socket is no longer on any room so... how am I supposed to achieve this? I was thinking making a ping-pong request stuff but no idea where should I put that.

Comment: I do not understand. Do you want to broadcast to other users that one of them disconnects from room? Or tell them that socket session closed?

Comment: Interested in this too. Yes I'd like to broadcast to other users that I'm disconnected.